# Are non-atomic writes safe to read if gated by an atomic operation?

Tags: rust, atomic

I want to create an object that is "empty" but can complex data (here `a` and `b`) that I can update later and set an atomic flag to mark it as non-empty so that it can be used in other threads. Pseudo example:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::{thread, time};

struct MyObject {
    is_empty: AtomicBool,
    a: Cell<u64>,
    b: Cell<u64>,
}

unsafe impl Sync for MyObject {}

fn main() {
    let obj = Arc::new(MyObject {
        is_empty: AtomicBool::new(true),
        a: Cell::new(0),
        b: Cell::new(0)
    });

    let thread_obj = obj.clone();
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        while thread_obj.is_empty.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
        }

        println!("a is: {}", thread_obj.a.get());
        println!("b is: {}", thread_obj.b.get());
    });

    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));

    obj.a.set(42);
    obj.b.set(5);
    obj.is_empty.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);

    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

See it on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8bbec1a8f1dc9988a3ca42bdf2439152)

It *seems* to work, but that doesn't mean much. I'm mostly concerned if the writes to `a` and `b` will definitely be visible to other threads that read `is_empty` as false. If I guarantee:

- all writes to `a` and `b` occur before setting the flag
- no thread reads `a` and `b` before the flag is set

is this ok?

I could use an `AtomicPtr` instead, create the object in full, and swap the pointer, but I'm curious if I can avoid the extra indirection.

Comment: The question would be, why do it this way instead of having the thread issue a blocking read on a channel, or waiting until after `obj` is initialized to spawn the thread?

Comment: In a real-world example the thread would be doing other things (in an abstract sense this object would affect how those things are done). This is a building-block of a more complicated system and I'm just curious if the idea here is unsound.

Comment: You could avoid all of this using https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/ to give the thread a channel to receive the config once it is generated.

Comment: unrelated, but `is_empty` might be better replaced by its opposite - `has_data`.  Try to avoid negatives, that lead to double-negatives (ie is_empty == false) they are just confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna use [Release and Acquire](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering) instead of [SeqCst](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering)

> Release :
>
> When coupled with a store, all previous operations become ordered before any load of this value with Acquire (or stronger) ordering. In particular, all previous writes become visible to all threads that perform an Acquire (or stronger) load of this value.
>
> Acquire :
>
> When coupled with a load, if the loaded value was written by a store operation with Release (or stronger) ordering, then all subsequent operations become ordered after that store. In particular, all subsequent loads will see data written before the store.

Change this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let obj = Arc::new(MyObject {
        is_empty: AtomicBool::new(true),
        a: Cell::new(0),
        b: Cell::new(0)
    });

    let thread_obj = obj.clone();
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        while thread_obj.is_empty.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
        }

        println!("a is: {}", thread_obj.a.get());
        println!("b is: {}", thread_obj.b.get());
    });

    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));

    obj.a.set(42);
    obj.b.set(5);
    obj.is_empty.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);

    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

Into :

```rust
fn main() {
    let obj = Arc::new(MyObject {
        is_empty: AtomicBool::new(true),
        a: Cell::new(0),
        b: Cell::new(0)
    });

    let thread_obj = obj.clone();
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        while thread_obj.is_empty.load(Ordering::Acquire){ // change
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
        }

        println!("a is: {}", thread_obj.a.get());
        println!("b is: {}", thread_obj.b.get());
    });

    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));

    obj.a.set(42);
    obj.b.set(5);
    obj.is_empty.store(false, Ordering::Release); //change

    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

Also see [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html) and [nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/atomics.html).

Comment: Huh, I think I misread the wording the first time thinking it applied to only other atomic operations, but it does say *"all previous writes become visible"*.